# Mann Whitney U test Vs T test

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, inference

Problem definition: I need to test whether the difference between the "mean" utilization metrics of two machines is statistically significant.

Given Data: Utilisation data is available for two machines for more than 100 days. Therefore, the mean, standard deviation, and standard error can be calculated over the 100 days.

My approach: Calculate the mean, standard error and then use t-test with unequal variances to test the difference in means. Used the approach described here "https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews73.pdf"

Clarifications: What is the best test here to test the statistical significance of the difference in "means"? Is it t-test or Mann Whitney u test? I read many academic papers where t-test is widely used than Mann Whitney U test (without testing for the normal distribution). Is it because they take the central limit theorem for granted and they use the t-test? Also, some claims that Mann Whitney U test is really not used to test the statistical significance of the means rather it is used for medians.

It's quite hard for me to understand the logic behind choosing these tests.

Comment: Maybe there is something more than just the mean that would be relevant to the comparison of the machines. Perhaps the size or distribution of the non-working intervals would be relevant too. For example, I would prefer my bicycle to be out of service for a continuous week than for it to be unavailable on seven separate days.

Answer (score -2):

In first place, t-test tests for means while Mann Whitney test tests for medians (under favourable assumptions - see Alexis's comment). However, if you can assume that your variable is symmetrically distribution, means are equal to medians.

In second place, unless your variable is not extremely skewed, you can use the central limit theorem to state that the mean is approximately normally distributed and then use t-test.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Do you recommend some thumb rules for the range of skewness values that can be used to assume the normality of the data? For example, the skewness of 0.2 is small enough for it to be assumed as a normal distribution? Of course, no data is perfectly normal. But a range of values would help to decide that.

Comment: A rule of thumb I read somewhere (although mostly related to other tests that also require normality) is to put a threshold for excess skewness and excess  kurtosis at 2. That is, skewness and kurtosis can't be more than 2 units far from those of normal. Since normal distribution has skewness=0 and kurtosis=3, that rule of thumb allows to use normal distribution based tests with skewnes in (-2, +2) and kurtosis in (1, 5).

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot. One more thought, if this needs to be made as an algorithmic approach and fed to a computer to automatically calculate it on a daily basis when a new data point arrives (and using the past 100 values), is it always safe to assume that the data would be "approximately" normal or should this condition needs to be checked every time and then choose the tests based on the results? Does this add more complexity to the algorithm design?

Comment: The Mann Whitney test **does not** test for difference in medians. It tests $H_{0}: P(X_{A} > X_{B}) = 0.5$ with $H_{A}: P(X_{A} > X_{B}) \ne 0.5$, that is, it tests a null hypothesis that a randomly selected observation from  group $A$ being greater than a randomly selected observation from group $B$ is one half (i.e. just as likely for $B$'s observation to be greater). The Mann Whitney test statistic can be interpreted as a test for median (**or mean**) difference *only* with additional assumptions met, namely, that (1) both groups have distributions with the same shape, & (2) same variance.

Comment: @Alexis Added to the answer. I wanted to keep the answer simple, as I think it fits better the OP's needs, but readers could benefit from having a second more detailed answer.

Comment: Pere, kudos for the dit, but there's still an inaccuracy. While means = medians for symmetric distributions, under the conditions I named (distributions of the same shape, with same variance), the Mann Whitney (Wilcoxon) test is ***still** a test of mean difference ***even for highly asymmetric distributions***.

Comment: Again: the simpler language is to describe the test as one looking for evidence of difference in "stochastic size" (sometimes folks will refer to this as 0th-order stochastic dominance), as indicated by the title of Mann and Whitney's paper: Mann, H. B. and Whitney, D. R. (1947). [On a test of whether one of two random variables is stochastically larger than the other](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177730491). *Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, 18:50–60.

Comment: Thank you @Alexis for a very clear explanation of Mann Whitney test. But can you please comment on the approach I have taken? Is it ok to use t-tests? I am planning to convert this into an algorithmic approach, in whenever a new data point arrives, the algorithm uses that data point plus previous 100 values to test for statistical significance in means. So my question is whenever a new data point arrives, I should check for the normality assumptions and then choose an appropriate test?

Comment: @Muk I see a few issues there. (1) one *can* use a $t$ test with non-normal data ***given a large enough sample size***, because the central limit theorem makes the distribution of sample means asymptotically normal. That said: $N=100$ doesn't sound like a very large sample size, and even with approximately normally-distributed observations, the *t* distribution will differ from the normal enough at that sample size to affect your *p*-values. What $\alpha$ are you interested in? More importantly *what question are you trying to answer with your approach?*

Comment: @Alexis. Thank you for your comment. I am trying to test the difference between the means of two data sets. And my aim is to make it a dynamic one i.e. testing for a difference in means whenever each new data point arrives ( a rolling window concept i.e. new data plus last 99 values). I am interested in alpha=0.05. I did try running t-tests and Whitney tests. Both actually gives the same results (of course the p values were different). But Mann Whitney tests includes a lot of computation, whereas t-tests are more straightforward and less computational stress. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Muk the rolling mean implies that successive tests are not at all independent. Can you step out for the bigger picture and tell me what question you are trying to answer with the whole approach? (I don't mean what tests are you trying to conduct... that you are trying to provide evidence that two time series are differ over a window of 100 observations is clear... but *why* are you doing this? What's the story here?)

Comment: @Alexis. yes. I can discuss the problem with you in detail. But due to confidentiality issues, I would like it to take it offline if thats ok with you

Comment: @Muk, please feel free to reach out by email (we could then move to phone if that worked better for you). I am alexisELEPHANTdinno@pdxMEGATHEREUMedu (where you substitute a period for any quadrupeds in the address.)

Comment: I give -1 because this answer is wrong.